# Combine c++ and javascript development in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, c++, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse IDE, but now I need it to develop apps for webOS.

Help me please with the next questions:

1. I have downloaded the Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web development. How can I find it's version information?
2. Can I use one instance of Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and C++ development at the same time? (if yes then please write the steps to extend JavaScript IDE to support C++ development) Or I should have two instances installed?
3. Some parts of documentation are written exactly for Eclipse Galileo C++ development. Are different versions of Eclipse IDE really different? Will I have problems porting settings from Galileo to Helios or Indigo?

Thanks.

Comment: @skaffman: Don't think that the topic has the direct relation to C++ or JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Usually Versioninformation can be found under `Help->About Eclipse`
2. I do not know about this exact setup but I have Java/C++/PHP in one Eclipse install.
   I installed the java version and then `Help->Install New Software` where I choose `-all sites-` as source and then searched for the compontent I wanted and installed it.
   After installation restart eclipse to load the new plugins and now you should have a new Perspective for the language you installed.
   If you can not find the perspective look under `Window->Open Perspective->Other`.
3. I do not know although I work with different version. Maybe some names (for example in menus) are changed but I really can't say (maybe a hint that they are not different? But Probably I just did not dive that deep into it).

The menu-paths I gave are under Indigo release.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I forgot to say that I am running Eclipse on Mac. And there is no `About Eclipse` in Help `:|`

Comment: @artyom.stv: Maybe that is a difference on my splashscreen there is no version to be seen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) with [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download) as a plugin which covers both bases for me.